# NameError occurring after calling nested function

Tags: python, list, function, file

So I split a .txt file into a list of lists (shown below). However, when I try to run `print(splitKeyword(keywords[1][0]))` to try and print the first element of the second list/element within keywordList, I get the error: `NameError: name 'keywordList' is not defined`. How can I fix this?

```
def functionOne(textFile):
        textFileVar = open(textFile, 'r')

    def splitKeyword(argument):
        keywordList = []
        for line in argument:
            keywordList.append(line.strip().split(','))
        return keywordList

    splitKeyword(textFileVar)
    print(keywordList[1][0])

results = functionOne("text1.txt")
print(results)
```

**This is the text1.txt/textFile/textFileVar contents**

> hello,world
>
> 123,456

**This is what keywordList looks like when printed:**

```
[[hello, world], [123, 456]]
```

Comment: you are returning from the function but not catching. so try to keywordList = splitKeyword(textFileVar) as keywordList is local to that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def functionOne(textFile):
        textFileVar = open(textFile, 'r')

    def splitKeyword(argument):
        keywordList = []
        for line in argument:
            keywordList.append(line.strip().split(','))
        return keywordList

    output = splitKeyword(textFileVar)
    print(output[1][0])
    return output

results = functionOne("text1.txt")
print(results)
```

look at `return keywordList` in `splitKeyword` function. it returns the value(`keywordList`). but in other scopes you can not access that variable, so you need to store that in something.

Comment: is the 'return output' needed? when I remove it, I get the console output I'm looking for but the word 'None' appears right under it

Comment: I think it is because of another line of your code. but remove it and check if you want.

Comment: when I keep return output, I don't get none, but when I remove it, i get none, will this cause any issues?

Comment: that is because of `results = functionOne("text1.txt")`. return output will return the value so `results` won't be empty(None), if you remove it, your function does not have any outputs so results would be None.

Answer (score 0):

Your `keywordList` is local to the function `splitKeyword()`, not to the function `functionOne()`. That's why you're getting a NameError.

Comment: @CosmicCat Well your function splitKeyword() returns something, so you might as well use this return right? Take what it returns in a variable and then use this variable to print it.

Answer (score 0):

keywordlist is a local variable to the function splitKeyword which return it so you can directly use this function and reduce the code.

```
def functionOne(textFile):
    textFileVar = open(textFile, 'r')
    def splitKeyword(argument):
        keywordList = []
        for line in argument:
            keywordList.append(line.strip().split(','))
        return keywordList

    print(splitKeyword(textFileVar))

results = functionOne("text1.txt")
print(results)
```